# Expressing relationship between two variables in pseudocode?

Tags: java, algorithm, function, time-complexity, runtime

I have some pseudocode I am trying to analyze:

```
public static void test(float z) {
  float y = 0;
  for (float i = 1; i <= z; i++) {
    if (y < z) {
      y = 4 * i * i + 6;
    }
  }
  return y;
}
```

From the function, I understand that `y = 4i^2 + 6` whenever `y < z`. However, I am having trouble capturing the relationship between y and z in an equation. I feel that it could be captured as a floor function (step function) -- for a certain range of numbers in z, y will have that specified value.

Comment: Shouldn't `z` in `z = 2 * i * i + 3;` be `y`?

Comment: yes, it should. thank you for catching that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` becomes greater than `z` (and stops changing) for the first `i` such that `2*i^2 + 3 > z`. In other words, a minimal `i > sqrt((z - 3) / 2)`, which is `floor(sqrt((z - 3)/2)) + 1`. Now as you know `i`, compute `y`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that helped clear up some stuff or me. However, when I substitute values for z such as 6 or 12, I'm not getting the values 11 and 21, respectively? Why is that?

Comment: It may be `i = floor(sqrt((z - 4) / 2)) + 1` (when z >= 4).

Comment: My question is more "Is there a way to directly get y in terms of z, without having to use i in the equation"?